# When writing a class/package, how can I run code if/when another package is loaded?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

I'm writing a thesis class file and I'd like to delay the running of code to *after* a specific package is loaded:

```
\AtEndOfOtherPackage{listings}{%
  \lstset{language=Python}}
```

Is there a command that already exists for the task?
If there isn't, how could it be effected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `scrlfile` you get `\AfterPackage`, that's executed only if the package is loaded, and at the end of it. So

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}

\AfterPackage{listings}{\lstset{language=Python}}
```

should be what you want.

Comment: Just to be clear, `#2` here is executed *immediately* after the package is loaded?  (I tried looking at the source of `scrlfile.sty`, but it is absolutely foreign to me…)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: This is definitely what I need then :) Thanks! It should be noted that this doesn't seem to work inside an `l3keys` spec, but that's another question entirely :)

Comment: @SeanAllred there are also variants `\AfterPackage*` (use code immediately if package is already loaded), `\AfterPackage+` (like star variant but if the package isn't completely loaded, yet, the code will not be used immediately but at the end of the package _before_ `\AtEndOfPackage` hook of the package) and `\AfterPackage!` (like + variant but code will be used _after_ `\AtEndOfPackage` hook of the package)

Answer (score 12):

If you need the package to be loaded, do as Herbert showed,

```
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}
```

If you want to conditionally run stuff after the package *if* the user loads that in the preamble then there is not (by default) an end of package hook usable for this (The hook used by `\AtEndOfPackage` is cleared as the package is loaded) So the normal thing is to use the begin document hook

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{listings}%
   {\typeout{yes}}%
   {\typeout{no}}%
 }
```

Comment: This is a great option, however it might confuse the user if they specifically `\lstset` something in the preamble and it is then overridden by the hook.

Comment: @SeanAllred package interface design would be easier if there were no users.

Comment: Comment of the *year*.

Answer (score 11):

```
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}
```

If it is already loaded before `\RequirePackage` nothing happens and `\lstset` will be used as usual.